# How can my nuget package copy .so files to the output?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a nuget package that provides a piece of functionality.  In that nuget package, there is a reference to libmediainfo, a third-party `.dll` file and `.so` file.  I have included them in my nuget package by adding the following to my `.csproj` file:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="libmediainfo.dll">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
        </Content>
        <Content Include="libmediainfo.so">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Now, when I include that package in my main project, only the third-party `.dll` file is copied to the bin directory, not the `.so` file.  I am running in a linux docker container and need both files to be copied.  This nuget package will be used in multiple places.  How can I get the consuming projects to include the `.so` file as well just by adding a reference to the nuget package?

Comment: Replace the `<PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>` with `<PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>`, then it can work. But note: You may need to clean the nuget cache first before creating a new console project and then consume the newly created package to do the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libmediainfo.dll` is one assembly, so it can be packed into lib folder. But `libmediainfo.so` is just simple file, it should be packed into content/[contentFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#using-the-contentfiles-element-for-content-files) folder. So you should remove the `<PackagePath>lib\$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>` line in second script.

```
<Content Include="libmediainfo.so">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
  <pack>true</pack>
</Content>
```

This is enough to get the `libmediainfo.so` packed into content/contentFiles folder. And if your main project consumes this package, build it and you'll see `libmediainfo.so` in its `bin` folder. (**PackageCopyToOutput** is what you're looking for !)

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.